# Setting default chrome on Android touch screen by adb command

Tags: android, adb, touch

I'm still learning, but
I'm trying to set chrome as a default browser on an android device using either a adb command or a script.

I tried using a customized version with `pm set-default-browser com.android.chrome --user 0`
but i'm not getting anything.

Has anyone something I can try?

Comment: What do you men by "I'm not getting anything"? Android command-line commands often create no output. Have you checked the default web browser by executing `cmd package resolve-activity http://www.example.com/`

Comment: It's not working is more accurate, sorry :)